# Good way to fix warning "field a is not used" if field is unused in configuration

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-warnings

I have a class with field, which i output to log. If log is turned off (For example in Release), i have warning (private field 'a_' is not used), because i use this field only to output to log.

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>

//#define TURNON_LOG

#ifdef TURNON_LOG
  #define  LOG(a) printf("%d", a)
#else
  #define  LOG(a) 0
#endif

class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a_(a)
    {
        LOG(a_);
    }

private:
    int a_;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I used clang with -Wall:

```
clang main.cpp -Wall
```

What is the best way to fix the warning in case, when TURNON_LOG is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define  LOG(a) ((void)a)
```

in the `#else` case should do the trick.

Small caveat: This will always evaluate the argument expression, even when logging is disabled. If the expression is just a variable, that will not matter, but for function calls etc, it might.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Baum mit Augen's answer, in the case of Clang (or any C++17 or later compiler) you can use the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute to silence warnings for specific possibly-unused variables.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a_(a)
    {
        LOG(a_);
    }

private:
    [[maybe_unused]] int a_;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

An extra solution to the already provided ones would be to #ifdef also the relevant parts.

Definitely not a good solution, which does not scale at all, but can do the trick in certain and limited cases:

```
class A
{
public:

#ifdef TURNON_LOG
    A(int a) : a_(a)
    {
        LOG(a_);
    }

private:
    int a_;
#else
    A(int) {}
#endif
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a(10);
    return 0;
}
```